# How to find how many cubes are in a n by n by n cube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I tried finding the answer using combinatoric by determining how many different length and width ans height are there for a cube, given the size of the bigger cube. But the formula I got turns out not working for some particular cases.

Comment: What did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We find out how many $k\times k\times k$ cubes there are in the big cube.

Put such a small cube at the bottom left-hand corner of the big cube. The bottom left-hand corner of the little cube can be put into $(n-k+1)\times(n-k+1)\times (n-k+1)$ positions. This is because that corner can be moved in any of the coordinate directions by any amount from $0$ to $n-k$.

Thus we want
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)^3.$$
This looks better as
$$\sum_{j=1}^n j^3.$$
There is a nice closed form formula for this sum, namely $\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: Oh no I wanted to ask about rectangles. But thanks I am gonna post it as a new problem.

Comment: You are welcome. So you wanted to find out about "boxes." That can be done too, but the solution has a somewhat different flavour. It is the natural generalization of the usual question of you have an $m\times n$ rectangle $R$ made up of $1\times 1$ squares. How many "subrectangles" does $R$ have? Yes, probably it should be a separate question. The solution will look much like the one for the $2$-dimensional version.

Comment: Rectangular prism including cubes*

Comment: Based on your explanation that rectangles are composed of square, I think I could first find out how many possible cubes there are in a big cube. Extending from there, if it is a cube on the edge of the big cube, then there are four ways to extend that cube.

Comment: But this may be to complex.